# Functions return number of times a scalar in a vector

Tags: r, function, if-statement, vector, scalar

I have to create a function

```
n_entries(v, x)
```

which, given a vector v and a scalar x and returns the number of times that x occurs in v.

Here is what I have so far:

```
n_entries = function (v,x) {
if(x %in% v) {
    return(sum(x %in% v))
  }
}
```

Example: n_entries(1:10, 1) should equal 1 and n_entries(c("a", "a", "b", "c"), "a") should equal 2. Thanks guys.

Comment: Use `sum(x==v)`. Don't bother with the `if`. `sum` will return 0 if not found which seems like the right answer.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I did the sum(x %in% v) and that wasn't working but sum(x==v) does! I feel dumb haha